# Django Deployment for Production

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have Django running on my local machine, but I am at the point to where I want to deploy my Django site to my production server. My server is an Ubuntu 14.04 server, with Apache 2.x, python 2.7, and Django 1.8. I have tried using Django's basic configuration for Apache and mod_wsgi [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/), but I keep getting the following error:

[my site](http://tmws.hardinresources.com/)

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Here is the error in the Apache Error Log I am receiving:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=14962): Target WSGI script '/var/www/tmws/tmws/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.,  
mod_wsgi (pid=14962): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/tmws/tmws/wsgi.py'.,  
Traceback (most recent call last):,  
File "/var/www/tmws/tmws/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>,  
  application = get_wsgi_application(),  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application,  
  django.setup(),  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup,  
  apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS),  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate,  
  app_config = AppConfig.create(entry),  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create,  
  module = import_module(entry),  
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module,  
  __import__(name),  
File "/var/www/tmws/django_tables2/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>,  
  from .tables import Table,  
File "/var/www/tmws/django_tables2/tables.py", line 15, in <module>,  
  from . import columns,  
File "/var/www/tmws/django_tables2/columns/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>,  
  from .base import library, BoundColumn, BoundColumns, Column,  
File "/var/www/tmws/django_tables2/columns/base.py", line 10, in <module>,  
  from django_tables2.utils import Accessor, AttributeDict, OrderBy, OrderByTuple,  
File "/var/www/tmws/django_tables2/utils.py", line 111, in <module>,  
  @six.python_2_unicode_compatible,  
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'python_2_unicode_compatible',
```

Here is my apache2.conf file:

```
...

<Directory /var/www/tmws/tmws>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

...

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/tmws/tmws/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/tmws
```

This is my wsgi.py file:

```
import os, sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/gather/src')
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')
sys.path.append('/var/www/tmws')
sys.path.append('/var/www/tmws/tmws')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "tmws.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

This is my websites .conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin xxxxxxxx
    ServerName xxxxxxxxxxx
    DocumentRoot /var/www/tmws
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/tmws/tmws/wsgi.py

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/TMWSerror.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/TMWSaccess.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If there is anything else I can post to help out let me know.

Comment: Are you running Django from a virtual environment? You probably should be. The issue is that you're using an old version of `six`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. No I am not using a Virtual environment, eventually I want to. What is six?

Comment: `six` is a python library. It should work if you upgrade it with `pip install --upgrade six` but doing so on the system python packages isn't ideal as you risk causing conflicts with other system packages - hence better to use a virtual environment.

Comment: That got it working! Post that as the answer and I will give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system is probably using an older version of the `six` python package that doesn't contain the `python_2_unicode_compatible` method. Upgrading six to the latest version should fix it:

```
pip install --upgrade six
```

That said, it is strongly advisable to run Django from a virtual environment instead of installing packages at the system level - if there are system packages that for some reason are dependent on the older version of `six` then you may run into other problems.